# Android java : Text-to-Speech no sound

Tags: java, android

Hi I'm new in Android Development.
I have doing a lot of research .
Everything go rights however there is no any output sound from the text I entered.
Did I miss out any important part ? 
The following bellow is the coding :

```
public class SpeechTextActivity extends Activity implements OnInitListener {

private int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;

private TextToSpeech tts;

private EditText inputText;
private Button speakButton;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_speech);

  inputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_speechText);
  speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_speechOut);

  speakButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
   String text = inputText.getText().toString();
   if (text!=null && text.length()>0) {
Toast.makeText(SpeechTextActivity.this, "Saying: " + text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
   }
   }
  });

  Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
  checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
  startActivityForResult(checkIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);

}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
            // success, create the TTS instance
            tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        } 
        else {
            // missing data, install it
            Intent installIntent = new Intent();
            installIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
            startActivity(installIntent);
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void onInit(int status) {        
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        Toast.makeText(SpeechTextActivity.this, 
                "Text-To-Speech engine is initialized", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if (status == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
        Toast.makeText(SpeechTextActivity.this, 
                "Error occurred while initializing Text-To-Speech engine", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

}
```

**Just now I test in my tablet it work! But in my phone not workable =(**

Comment: Which device in run this app? Toast message is successfully display? @Frozen

Comment: @JigarShekh Omg ! I dont know how to thanks you ! Man you are genius! thanks you so so much !!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the implements **OnInitListener**   to  **TextToSpeech.OnInitListener**.

Answer (score 0):

Try to unplug the USB cable from your phone before testing. TTS is recognized to encountered some issues in debug mode.